# How to fix "address already in use" error when attempting to launch geth console?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I'm downloading the chain and I've processed more than 2 million blocks so far. I'm trying to attach to the geth console to view the syncing status, but I've tried typing `geth console` in another terminal (on Mac) and I get an error:

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use
```

If I've understood correctly I should type `geth console` and then `eth.syncing`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is most likely because the geth is already running and when you are trying to start another geth process using the same 30303 default port. If you know the datadir of the geth process which is downloading the chain, find a geth.ipc file in that datadir and use `geth attach ipc:<geth.ipc path>` to connect to the existing process.

Comment: Apparently there is no ipc file in the datadir... It's full of Idb though.

Comment: ldb files should be present in the chaindata folder. Try doing `cd ../..` and geth.ipc file should be present there.

Comment: this doesn't work for me: `$ geth attach ipc:~/.ethereum/geth.ipc                                                     │·······················································
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such fi│·······················································
le or directory  `

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux then go to terminal and run the following commands:

```
 $ netstat -p || grep 30303
    $ kill -9 `process id`
```

Comment: I think you mean `|` (pipe) rather than `||` (or). Also, please don't use `kill` with `-9`. It equates to a `SIGKILL`, which means "kill the process immediately". If your Geth instance is currently writing to disk, you're asking for a corrupt database... Use a signal that can be caught by Geth's signal handlers (e.g. `SIGINT` using `kill -INT <pid>`).